# I want to design a given discrete time signal sampled as Python and see the result in a picture

Tags: python

[image]

and this signal is sampling by continuous time signal x(t)

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? You will have to explain more than that. What exactly do you want to achieve with the sampled signal?

Comment: The whole code of python I don't know what to do

Comment: Nobody will know what to do unless you explain what exactly you want. What does "show the Discrete Time Signal to an Image" mean? Do you want to plot it or something? A little explanation of your issue would be a lot better.

Comment: Ok I'll change my question

Comment: You can implement the given function in python, store the data for different (x,n). For plotting you can use matplotlib, something like `plt.plot(x_list, n_list)` or scatter plot